# Does iOS 13.3 have haptic touch app switcher?

Tags: iphone, ios, haptic-feedback

When I was using iOS 12 (Final version) it has the 3D touch app switcher to switch between apps instantly.

After that when iOS 13 launched publicly, it replaced 3D touch with haptic touch which is simply holding and pressing for a long time to popups and other 3D touch use cases.

But I couldn't find any ways to switch apps using haptic touch in iOS 13? Are there any mechanisms in iOS 13.3?

I have iPhone 7 Plus running on 13.2.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does iOS 13.3 have haptic touch app switcher?

Yes. On your iPhone, you can press and hold on the left edge of the display to bring up the iOS multitasking UI/app switcher.

[image]